# Swift extension only when conforming to Class AND protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have two protocols with extensions `LoginPresenting` and `LoginDismissing`. I want `LoginPresenting` extension only to apply to `UIViewControllers` that also implement `LoginDismissing`. I am trying to do it like so but have so far been unable to work out the syntax.

```
protocol LoginDismissing : class {
    func loginHasCompleted(withController: UIViewController)
}

extension LoginDismissing where Self:UIViewController {
    func loginHasCompleted(withController controller:UIViewController) {
        //...code ommited
    }
}

protocol LoginPresenting : class {
    func presentLogin()
}
```

The following is **bad code**, but I think it explains how I am attempting to make LoginPresenting only apply to UIViewControllers that also implement LoginDismissing.

```
extension LoginPresenting where Self:UIViewController, LoginDismissing //Syntax error here

    func presentLogin() {
        let lc = LoginViewController()
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: lc)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        lc.loginDismissingDelegate = self //type LoginDismissing
        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enforce as many requirements as possible on the protocol itself, not the extensions.

```swift
protocol LoginPresenting: LoginDismissing & UIViewController {
  func presentLogin()
}
```

Also, `class` is old syntax, though not deprecated.

```swift
protocol LoginDismissing: AnyObject {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve your syntax error with the use of `&` instead of a comma:

```swift
extension LoginPresenting where Self: UIViewController & LoginDismissing {
    // ...
}
```

This makes the extension only apply to view controllers that also conform to `LoginDismissing`.